# Adding 'region' column based on 'state' column value but 'region' values all the same

Tags: python-3.x, function

I have a df 'beersmerged' which contains a column 'state'.  I am attempting to create a column 'region' which evaluates the value in 'state' and adds the appropriate value to 'region'.

This code runs without error and creates the 'region' column, but every row has the same value - None.  I've tried several other approaches and they all have a similar result in that they put the same value in every row.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

```
def get_region(state, *region):
    if state in region[0]:
        return 'New_England'
    elif state in region[1]:
        return 'Mid_Atlantic'
    elif state in region[2]:
        return 'South'
    elif state in region[3]:
        return 'Midwest'
    elif state in region[4]:
        return 'Southwest'
    elif state in region[5]:
        return 'West'
    else:
        return None

New_England = ['CT', 'ME', 'MA', 'NH', 'RI', 'VT']
Mid_Atlantic =  ['DC', 'DE', 'MD', 'NJ', 'NY', 'PA']
South = ['AL', 'AR', 'FL', 'GA', 'KY', 'LA', 'MS', 'MO', 'NC', 'SC', 'TN', 'VA', 'WV']
Mid_West = ['IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'MI', 'MN', 'NE', 'ND', 'OH', 'SD', 'WI']
Southwest = ['AZ', 'NM','OK', 'TX']
West = ['AK', 'CA', 'CO', 'HI', 'ID', 'MT', 'NV', 'OR', 'UT', 'WA', 'WY']

region = [New_England, Mid_Atlantic, South, Midwest, Southwest, West]
beersmerged['region'] = beersmerged['state'].apply(get_region, args=(region))
beersmerged.head()
```

I've also tried this using the lists above and it runs without error but puts a 0 for 'region' in every row:
class_regions ={'New_England':New_England,'Mid_Atlantic':Mid_Atlantic,'South':South,'Midwest':Midwest,'Southwest':Southwest,'West':West}
dict_cond_values = {key:beersmerged['state'].isin(class_regions[key]) for key in class_regions}
beersmerged['region']=np.select(dict_cond_values.values(),dict_cond_values.keys())
beersmerged.head()

I was expecting something like this:

```
state   region
OR  West
IN  Midwest
TX  Southwest
NH      New_England
VA      Mid_Atlantic
```

But get this:

```
state   region
OR  None
IN  None
TX  None
NH      None
VA      None
```

Comment: I think * is not necessary in "def get_region(state, *region)".

Comment: I don't fully understand the mechanics of the starred expression, but without it I get an error "get_region() takes 2 positional arguments but 7 were given"...it tries to take all the lists at once vs iterating through them.

Comment: Btw, try args=(region,) adding comma in yoir original version to specify that (region,) is a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

In the original version, specify with a comma that the type of args is tuple as it's required and get rid of asterisk * in front of region parameter of the get_region.

```
get_region(state, region):
...
beersmerged['region'] = beersmerged['state'].apply(get_region, args=(region,))
```

But I think it's better to use dict instead of list.

```
def get_region(state, region):
    if state in region['New_England']:
        return 'New_England'
    elif state in region['Mid_Atlantic']:
        return 'Mid_Atlantic'
    elif state in region['South']:
        return 'South'
    elif state in region['Midwest']:
        return 'Midwest'
    elif state in region['Southwest']:
        return 'Southwest'
    elif state in region['West']:
        return 'West'
    else:
        return None

New_England = ['CT', 'ME', 'MA', 'NH', 'RI', 'VT']
Mid_Atlantic =  ['DC', 'DE', 'MD', 'NJ', 'NY', 'PA']
South = ['AL', 'AR', 'FL', 'GA', 'KY', 'LA', 'MS', 'MO', 'NC', 'SC', 'TN', 'VA', 'WV']
Mid_West = ['IL', 'IN', 'IA', 'KS', 'MI', 'MN', 'NE', 'ND', 'OH', 'SD', 'WI']
Southwest = ['AZ', 'NM','OK', 'TX']
West = ['AK', 'CA', 'CO', 'HI', 'ID', 'MT', 'NV', 'OR', 'UT', 'WA', 'WY']

region = {'New_England': New_England, 'Mid_Atlantic': Mid_Atlantic, 'South': South, 'Midwest': Midwest, 'Southwest': Southwest, 'West': West}
beersmerged['region'] = beersmerged['state'].apply(get_region, args=(region,))
beersmerged.head()
```

Comment: I figured it out.  My original code worked...the problem was with the values in the state column...they had a space in front of the values.  I'm dumb.  Your code worked as well...thanks for working with me!